# How to return sum of unknown fields' name?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data like this, and want to calculate how many i have true/false values for all fields

```
{
    "key1" : true,
    "key2" : false,
    "key3" : true
},
{
    "key1" : false,
    "key2" : true,
    "key3" : true
}
```

Expected result is

```
{
  key1: { true: 1, false: 1 },
  key2: { true: 1, false: 1 },
  key3: { true: 2, false: 0 }
}
```

I can calc it for specific field with group by operator, but i don't know how to do this for all fields in collection

Answer (score 2):

Closest you can get is this:

```
db.foo.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        key1 : { 
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: "$key1",
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        },
        key2 : { 
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: "$key2",
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        },
        key3 : { 
            $sum: {
                $cond: {
                    if: "$key3",
                    then: 1,
                    else: 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Which will give you:

```
{
    "_id" : null,
    "key1" : 1,
    "key2" : 1,
    "key3" : 2
}
```

Comment: looks good, but problem is that i don't know keys actually will be in the collection, something like — key1, key2, ... key-n where n is random

Comment: I don't know of a single command that can achieve that, however you can construct the aggregation on the client with a string concatenation.  It'll still get executed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

If you have no idea of the number of keys' name in you document, then you can't use the aggregation framework, instead what you need here is [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) and output the map reduce result into a new collection using the [`out` option](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#out-options) or display the result in the shell using `inline: 1`. Here we the option is used  because we need extra processing step in order to get the expect result.

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() { 
        var keys = Object.keys(this); 
        for(var ind=0; ind<keys.length; ind++) { 
            if (keys[ind] !== "_id") {
                var d = {}; 
                d.name = keys[ind], 
                d.value= this[keys[ind]]; 
                emit(d, 1);
            }
        }
    },
    function(key, values) { return Array.sum(values); }, 
    { "out": "mresult" }
)
```

which returns something like this:

```
{
        "result" : "mresult",
        "timeMillis" : 566,
        "counts" : {
                "input" : 2,
                "emit" : 6,
                "reduce" : 1,
                "output" : 5
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Five documents where saved in the newly created collection as shown by the `mapReduce` output. You can easily very this using the [`.find()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

```
db.mresult.find()
```

which yields something like this:

```
{ "_id" : { "name" : "key1", "value" : false }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "key1", "value" : true }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "key2", "value" : false }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "key2", "value" : true }, "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "name" : "key3", "value" : true }, "value" : 2 }
```

As you can see even using `mapReduce` we can't get the expected result which is somehow a bit annoying, but these documents can easily be processed using the [`.aggregate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method.

The first stage in you pipeline is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage where you basically use the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) conditional operator to "set" the value of "true" and "false". The last stage in the pipeline is the `$group` stage where you group your documents and use the `$sum` accumulator operator to return the sum for each group.

```
db.mresult.aggregate([
    { "$project": { 
        "true": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$_id.value", true ] }, 
                "$value", 
                0
            ]
        }, 
        "false": { 
            "$cond": [
                { "$eq": [ "$_id.value", false ] }, 
                "$value", 
                0
            ]
        }
    }}, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id.name", 
        "true": { "$sum": "$true" }, 
        "false": { "$sum": "$false" } 
    }}
])
```

which produces something like this:

```
{ "_id" : "key3", "true" : 2, "false" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "key2", "true" : 1, "false" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "key1", "true" : 1, "false" : 1 }
```

Of course this is not exactly you expected output but much more better because, generally speaking using data as key is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with callback passed to `find` query. it will give you more flexibility.

```
    Sample.find({}, function (err, docs) {
        if (!err) {
            var result = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
                var currDoc = docs[i]._doc;
                delete currDoc._id;
                Object.keys(currDoc).forEach(function (key) {
                    var processedKey = result[key] ? result[key] : {"false": 0, "true": 0};
                    var count = (processedKey["" + currDoc[key]] | 0 ) + 1;
                    processedKey["" + currDoc[key]] = count;
                    result[key] = processedKey;
                });
            }
            console.log(result);
            process.exit();
        } else {
            throw err;
        }
    });
```

for input

```
[
    {
        "key1": true,
        "key2": false,
        "key3": true
    },
    {
        "key1": true,
        "key2": false,
        "key3": true
    }
]
```

It will output

```
{
    key3: {
        false: 0,
        true: 2
    },
    key2: {
        false: 2,
        true: 0
    },
    key1: {
        false: 0,
        true: 2
    }
}
```

Comment: it works, but i want to execute this calculation in the database, not on the client side